# Prevent Entity Framework from inserting default value

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table with a column

```
[ChangeDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate())
```

But when I insert values into it using EF context, it fills `ChangeDate` with a default value `0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000`, because I don't specify value for this column in my C# code.

How can I prevent EF from inserting any value in this column? Because I always want to have `GetDate()` result in this column after insert.

I use db first approach.

Comment: Does making property Nullable help? Nullable property should default to null.

Comment: I have used GetDate() initially, then converted to GetUTCDate(), then I realized I should just set the time from the web application by using DateTime.UtcNow.  I am certain if you are using .edmx you can alter the model column to StoreGeneratedPattern - Computed and not have to pass in a value on insert/update.

Comment: EF6 I guess (not Core)? Marking the property with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` would do what you want, but also will prevent updating the vaue.

Comment: @IvanStoev yes, i also will use trigger in db to update this field automatically, when entry changes.

Comment: @nuclearsweet Then it should work for you :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Why is this a better option as opposed to setting the time within your application (which would likely provide more flexibility)

Comment: @confusedandamused I didn't say it is better option. It's just what OP asked for.

Comment: @nuclearsweet You can also override `SaveChanges` in your `DbContext` to set the `ChangeDate = DateTime.UtcNow` if you have some sort of base class all of your entities inherit from. Alternatively, you can reflect over them a look for a property called `ChangeDate` that is a `DateTime` on each changed entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

Modify SQL table column definition  `(getutcdate())`

Modify Entity Framework EDMX column property:

```
StoreGeneratedPattern : Computed
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better idea to delete his current DB schema in designer, and then make changes within MSSQL Server and update his designer?  I've had it not properly apply changes when only changing .edmx properties.

Comment: 9/10 updating your designed from database is easiest route to take. Albeit the issue here is before the CLR takes the query and converts it to SQL the value will have to be computed to not apply the updated time value to the insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the property as nullable - `DateTime?`

```
public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
```

Please see the difference between CreatedDate and ModifiedDate

Comment: This depends on what type of Entity Framework setup he is using (DB First/Code First/etc).  He would likely be better off editing his DB/Schema then updating his .edmx files.  If he used your answer the changes wouldn't be saved after an update since it is auto-generated.

Comment: You can't put a null value in a db first approach that has the `not null` specified in the db...

Answer (score -1):

When inserting to that column to get the current datetime you can do the following.  (I think this is what you are looking for - if not let me know and I can edit).

By doing it this way you are pushing the current DateTime to your DB, so it will use getdate() at the DB level.

Datatype should be datetime, allow nulls, and default value or binding is set to getdate() in SQL Server.

```
MyEntity myEntityInstance = new MyEntity();

myEntity.ChangeDate = DateTime.now;
_db.EntityClass.Add(myEntityInstance);

_db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you filled your datetime property in your class constructor?

something like

```
public YourClassName() {
    yourDateTime = DateTime.Now;
}
```